# Calculating time to mount the screen in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

There was a couple of questions that are related to this topic but none of them has a proper answer. So what I want to do is calculating the time to navigate to a screen. so basically timer starts here ;

```
navigation.navigate("SomePage")
```

so it should start some kind of timer every time the navigation function is fired.

I can end the timer on NavigationContainer with onStateChange;

```
<NavigationContainer
        ref={navigationRef}
        onStateChange={() => // I can end timer here}
      >
```

So how can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you concerned with the time of navigation, or the time mounting the screen?  I think the time of navigation will be negligible, and mounting will always be the costly operation.

React 16.9 made the [Profiler component](https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html) stable, which includes an API for measuring mount times of whole screens or even subsets of screens.  You would wrap the component(s) you want to measure in the Profiler component:

```js
import React, { Profiler } from 'react';
...

<Profiler onRender={onRender}>
  <View>
    ...
</Profiler>
```

The onRender prop is required, and has the following signature (as of React 17.0.1, which is bundled with RN 64):

```js
function onRenderCallback(
  id, // the "id" prop of the Profiler tree that has just committed
  phase, // either "mount" (if the tree just mounted) or "update" (if it re-rendered)
  actualDuration, // time spent rendering the committed update
  baseDuration, // estimated time to render the entire subtree without memoization
  startTime, // when React began rendering this update
  commitTime, // when React committed this update
  interactions // the Set of interactions belonging to this update
) {
  // Aggregate or log render timings...
}
```

Probably the easiest way is to subtract startTime from commitTime when the phase is `'mount'`.